# i'm confused with the "read" method of the ChannelOutboundHandle in netty framework

Tags: java, netty

I'v got no idea about the "read" method of the ChannelOutboundHandle.
why this method occurred in the ChannelOutboundHandle, what's its for?
cause the outboundHandlers are used to handle the output, they are usually
used to write data to wire.
and also I got a problem when I'm using the "read" method.I wrote a EchoServer by netty. here is my code:

```
public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this handler is sharable
        final EchoServerInboundHandler echoServerInboundHandler = new EchoServerInboundHandler();
        EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        // setup group
        serverBootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup)
                // setup channelFactory
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                // listening port
                .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(8080))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast(echoServerInboundHandler);
                        pipeline.addLast(new EchoServerOutboundHandler());
                    }
                });

        try {
            ChannelFuture f = serverBootstrap.bind().sync();
            f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        System.out.println(future.channel().localAddress()+" started!");
                    }
                }
            });
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            // release all threads
            eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully().syncUninterruptibly();

        }

    }
}
```

---

```
 public class EchoServerOutboundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void read(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("read");
        //super.read(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("msg:"+msg);
        super.write(ctx, msg, promise);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.flush(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

---

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class EchoServerInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("client:"+ctx.channel().remoteAddress()+" connected!");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("client:"+ctx.channel().remoteAddress()+" disconnected!");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("EchoServerInboundHandler registered");
        super.channelRegistered(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("EchoServerInboundHandler unregistered");
        super.channelUnregistered(ctx);
    }
}
```

as U can see, I comment the `super.read(ctx);` in the `read` method of the `EchoServerOutboundHandler` which cause a problem that it can't write data to the client. and also I found that this method will be called when a client established a connection.

Comment: https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.html#read-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-

Comment: @cricket_007 I'v seen that already, it seems no use to me.

Comment: Well, do you understand what `@Override` and `super()` actually do? Forget about Netty

Comment: @cricket_007 `@Override means` to rewrite the super class's method and super means to call the super class's method.

Comment: Right, and if you override and don't call super, then nothing is done by the parent object, or the framework/lifecycles that it is a part of

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need to provide the same code that the [parent object would do in the super() method](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java#L91-L94), which is `ctx.read()`

Which is what the JavaDoc says...

> Calls `ChannelHandlerContext.read()` ...

Otherwise, all you're doing is printing something on your own, and not using Netty to handle anything.

Comment: I got what U wanna say. But I still wanna find out the usage of the `read` method .

Comment: Maybe you should refer to the documentation for `ChannelHandlerContext`, then, but it's a networking library. Somewhere you need to *read the socket inputstream*

Comment: OK，appreciate it.